# How can I use parameters in gradle tasks?

Tags: gradle

There are many tasks that come with gradle which use parameters.

```
gradle test --tests *Test
gradle dependencyInsight --dependency junit
```

How can I access parameters in my own custom tasks?

Comment: Out of interest - what's the concrete use-case for this?

Comment: I have a rule in a multiproject that prints legacy ant info for each project type that matches. I can do things like ant report Java or antReportJavaScript and only those types get in the report. I think it would be nicer to have parameters for the type and format (csv, wiki) instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The functionality you're looking for is part of the public API **starting with Gradle 4.6**: See [release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#tasks-api-allows-custom-command-line-options) and [user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:declaring_and_using_command_line_options).

A more recent link to the user guide (v8.1.1): https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:declaring_and_using_command_line_options

Just tested this (build.gradle):

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.options.Option

class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    @Option(option="funky", description="test")
    @Input
    String myOption
    
    @TaskAction
    void echoOption() {
        logger.lifecycle("Value of 'myOption': ${myOption}")
    }
}

task myTask(type: MyTask) {
}
```

Result:

```bash
❯ gradle myTask --funky=bar

> Task :myTask
Value of 'myOption': bar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 399ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: Current versions of Gradle require an annotation of `@Input` before `String myOption`.

Comment: Thanks @User51  I updated the answer, and provided a more recent documentation link.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider passing the -P argument in invoking Gradle.

From [Gradle Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html) :

> --project-prop Sets a project property of the root project, for example -Pmyprop=myvalue. See Section 14.2, “Gradle properties and
>   system properties”.

Considering this build.gradle

```
task printProp << {
    println customProp
}
```

Invoking Gradle -PcustomProp=myProp will give this output :

```
$ gradle -PcustomProp=myProp printProp
:printProp
myProp

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.722 secs
```

This is the way I found to pass parameters.