# Gradle: passing properties

Tags: gradle, parameter-passing

I have Java, Gradle app and I want to pass several arguments when launching it.
The command needs to be of format:

```
gradle run -access X -resource Y -page Z
```

I have no experience with Gradle. If you'd be so kind to help, please ELI5 :)

**UPDATE:** Okay, I'm almost there.

```
run {
standardInput = System.in
systemProperties System.getProperties()
}
```

Code above allows me to do `gradle run -Daccess X -Dresource Y -Dpage Z`.
Can I make it w/o prefix `D`?

Comment: Consider the top answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231889/how-can-i-use-parameters-in-gradle-tasks).  There, a task class def is defined mid-Gradle file, an @Option flag is added, and then a task is created of that type.  If you did this often, you could consider a plugin to do the same.  Of course, if you wanted a simpler solution, you could just wrap your call to gradle in a scripting language of your choice (bash, python, powershell, batch file, etc).

There,